# Why does my for loop return an empty list value at the end of the list?

Tags: python

I have written a simple piece of Python code that is supposed to compare the list `current_usernames` (users that are trying to log in) to the list `usernames` (users that have already logged in). If a user from `current_usernames` is already in `usernames`, the user will be rejected otherwise the user will be greeted. If there are no users in `current_usernames`, there should be just an output saying: *`There are no users in the system at this point`*.

**Code**:

```
usernames = ["User1", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User5", "Admin"]
current_usernames = ["User6", "User7", "User3", "User8", "User5"]

for current_user in current_usernames:
    if current_user not in usernames:
        if current_user == "Admin":
            print("Hello Admin!!! Welcome back!")
        else:
            print("Hello " + current_user)
    else:
        print("Sorry, " + current_user + " is already logged in.")
else:
    print("There are no users in the system at this point!")
```

**Output:**

```
Hello User6 
Hello User7
Sorry, User3 is already logged in.
Hello User8
Sorry, User5 is already logged in.
There are no users in the system at this point!
```

**Question:**

Why does for loop return *`There are no users in the system at this point!`* at the end of the loop?

I was expecting for loop to stop after `Hello User5` since there are no more users in the `current_usernames` left.

Comment: You will get an explanation here: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `else` clause of a `for` loop is triggered any time the loop completes normally, rather than through a `break` statement. Since your loop does not contain a `break`, the `else` will always be triggered.

The idea behind the `else` clause is to make it easier to write something like a linear search:

```
for x in sequence:
    if x == key:
        print('found it')
        break
else:
    print('Not found')
```

It appears that you have confused the `else` following a `for` loop and the `else` normally found in a conditional statement the following would do what you want:

```
if current_users:
    for current_user in current_usernames:
       ...
else:
    print('No users currently trying to get into the system')
```

Comment: Yes, the if statement suggestion at the beginning fixed it! Thanks for the help and the the explanation on the break statement.

Comment: @Arash. It's a very obscure construct that dates to the beginning of the language. Nowadays there are much more convenient constructs for just about every use case, so not many people come across it.